# Sharing Rule to share custom Obj

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-rule

I haven't worked on Sharing Rule Before can anyone please help me.

I want to share 'Story' custom Object. When Share checkbox is checked, share Story record with Role and Hierarchy - Exec Director

OWD for this Obj is set to Private.

What are the ways and which is best way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't worked on Sharing Rule Before can anyone please help me.

So this is high time you start learning about Sharing Rules. A good place to start is the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_security/units/data_security_sharing_rules) and reading through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_about_sharing_rules.htm). You will find lots of resources on how to get more information about Sharing Rules.

As for your question, and assuming the "Share" checkbox is a custom field on your "Story" object, your best bet here is a [criteria based sharing rule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm).

> Criteria-based sharing rules determine whom to share records with based on field values in records. For example, let’s say you use a custom object for job applications, with a custom picklist field named “Department.” A criteria-based sharing rule could share all job applications in which the Department field is set to “IT” with all IT managers in your organization.

I will recommend, take a look at how you can configure the rules, build those and test it out. Hope this helps.